# Unable to connect to AWS storage gateway EC2 instance from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, aws-storage-gateway

I am trying to create a AWS file gateway using an EC2 instance. After the instance has been created, I am not able to connect to the instance using the IP address of the instance. I have edited my inbound rules to accept connections from the port 80, 3260,3389 and 443. Is there anything else i have missed ?

Comment: Well what error do you get? We need more information

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your settings. But you can follow this link first [Troubleshooting Connecting to Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html) .